# Total Difference in a Table row Jquery Dynamically

Tags: jquery

How I will to do this in Jquery. I would like to output the total difference of each table row dynamically. Thanks

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td><input value = "5"/></td>
      <td><input value = "3"/></td>          
      <td class="total_diff">2</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td><input value = "10"/></td>
      <td><input value = "3"/></td>
      <td class="total_diff">7</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td><input value = "16"/></td>
      <td><input value = "4"/></td>
      <td class="total_diff">12</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over the `tr` elements using the [`.each()` method](https://api.jquery.com/each/), grab the values of the `input` elements based on the `td` element index (using the [`:eq()` selector](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/)), subtract the values and add the text.

```js
$('table tr').each(function() {
  var firstValue = parseInt($(this).find('td:eq(0) input').val(), 10),
      secondValue = parseInt($(this).find('td:eq(1) input').val(), 10);
      
  $(this).find('.total_diff').text(firstValue - secondValue);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
   <tr>
      <td><input value="5"/></td>
      <td><input value="3"/></td>          
      <td class="total_diff"></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td><input value="10"/></td>
      <td><input value="3"/></td>
      <td class="total_diff"></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td><input value="16"/></td>
      <td><input value="4"/></td>
      <td class="total_diff"></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```